# Linux: inconsistency reported by 'du'

Tags: linux, du

```
xrfang@lky-web-02:/tmp/nnrres/ready$ ls -alh
total 249M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 249M Oct 27 08:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4.0K Oct 17 22:35 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  303 Oct 24 13:11 16f4cf33b85256f604ea0047348c48bb.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  303 Oct 11 09:25 5d831f03f9945524ab71bdbaa7f0a63f.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  303 Oct 23 11:01 6635e0ed3d8397449c125e589268e58e.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  303 Oct 23 13:57 665b54935b7ce8b6c994ec9a84174b7d.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  305 Sep 30 09:22 773a0ca22e3ba65152164fb9fc946745.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  303 Oct 26 11:21 9ed57a9652ff74c8f5e464d9b6003d77.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  303 Sep 19 11:10 a54f7c9c9bb82c299ef776ec8491e947.json
xrfang@lky-web-02:/tmp/nnrres/ready$
```

As seen above, the total size of all files in the directly is merely a few KB, but the size of "." is about 250MB!  That big number is reported by the `du` command.  How can this happen, and how to rectify?

BTW, the server runs Debian Linux 10.

Comment: Ext family? [Why directory with large amounts of entries does not shrink in size after entries are removed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495181/108618)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think that's the problem.  Do you know if this problem exists only on ext file system? How about other format such as XFS/JFS/ReiserFS etc?

Comment: Possibly some process is still holding delete filenames. see https://serverfault.com/questions/232525/df-in-linux-not-showing-correct-free-space-after-file-removal

Comment: XFS will have this problem too.